# Iteration equation

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I am very new to R and am in need of some help. I am trying to write code for the following:

```
suppose x[0]=1 and  
x[j]=x[j-1]+(2/x[j-1])  
for j=1,2,...  
Write a program to find the first 10 values, i.e. x[0],x[1],...x[9]
```

I believe I have to write a `for()`
loop but I am struggling to get the right combination. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here is where I'm at right now:

```
x=1
for(j in 1:10){
  x=x[j-1]+(2/x[j-1]) 
  print(x)
}
```

Yes, this is for homework. The x[0] is supposed to be x (subscript) 0. I'm unsure how to write that any other way.

Comment: might i recommend that you a) simply search for loops, b) show what you have done, and c) it may be prudent to explicitly state this is homework?

Comment: Also, fwiw, vector indices start at 1 in R, so `x[0]` isn't valid in R.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1) The goal should probably be to create a vector `x` with 10 elements

2) In R, vector indicies start at 1 (instead of 0), so you have that x[1] = 1.

3) In R, a single number is in fact a vector of length 1, so you can initiate this vector by writing `x <- 1`

4) Since you already have the first element and the loop uses the preceding element to create the next element, the loop should start at j = 2.

5) In R, when you assign an element to a vector outside its length, R will expand the vector to the necessary length. I.e. you can write

```
x <- 1
x[2] <- 3.14
```

and have a vector x = [1, 3.14]

So the setup can look like this:

```
x <- 1
for(j in 2:10){
   #do stuff to generate the x vector
}
```